# SwiftUI 3.0 for macOS: how to set .frame to open at maximum screen space

Tags: macos, swiftui

Goal:  set .frame to open at maximum screen space

What I did:

```
ContentView()
.frame(minWidth: 700, idealWidth: .infinity, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 500, idealHeight: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
```

Problem: the frame still opens at the minHeight and minWidth.

Question: How can I set frame, so it will always open according to the full user device screen?

Comment: I did not tried by myself, but I think it must be done in this way, you have to read the monitor/screen size then set that size as frame.

Comment: try: `.frame(minWidth: NSScreen.main?.frame.width, minHeight: NSScreen.main?.frame.height)`

Comment: perfect, worked! I cannot accept this as answer as you commented, not answered. If you want to have it accepted please reply an answer : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try using:

```
 .frame(minWidth: NSScreen.main?.frame.width, minHeight: NSScreen.main?.frame.height)
```

works for me on macos 12.1 beta